# Proving that Legendre Polynomial is orthogonal

Tags: orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

This is from [here](http://planetmath.org/orthogonalityoflegendrepolynomials)

$$\int^1_{-1}f_n(x)P_n(x)dx = 2(-1)^n\frac{a_n}{2^n}\int^1_0(x^2-1)^ndx=2(-1)^n\frac{a_n}{2^n}.I_n$$........(6)

I don't understand as in shouldnt it be like this, $$\int^1_{-1}f_n(x)P_n(x)dx = (-1)^n\frac{a_n}{2^n}\int^1_{-1}(x^2-1)^ndx=0$$ as they should cancel out even if the integral is non-zero.

Edited: Lastly, how does $\int^1_{-1}f_n(x)P_n(x)dx$ shows orthogonality?

Comment: Here $f_n$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $\le n$.  If $f_n$ is of lower degree then the coefficient $a_n$ is $0$.  In particular $\int P_m(x) P_n(x)\, dx = 0$ for any $m<n$.  By symmetry this is also true when $m>n$, i.e. for $m\ne n$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a much simpler proof from *Special Functions and Their Applications* by N. N. Lebedev.

We begin with Legendre's differential equation
\begin{equation}
[(1-x^{2})P^{\prime}_{n}(x)]^{\prime} +n(n+1)P_{n}(x) = 0,\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}_{0}^{+}
\label{eq:lp1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

The first step is to multiple equation \eqref{eq:lp1} by $P_{m}(x)$ and subtract it from equation \eqref{eq:lp1} written for $m$ and multiplied by $P_{n}(x)$.

\begin{equation}
[(1-x^{2})P^{\prime}_{m}(x)]^{\prime}P_{n}(x) \,-\, [(1-x^{2})P^{\prime}_{n}(x)]^{\prime}P_{m}(x) + [m(m+1)-n(n+1)]P_{m}(x)P_{n}(x) = 0
\end{equation}

Rearrangement yields
\begin{equation}
\{(1-x^{2})[P^{\prime}_{m}(x)P_{n}(x)-P^{\prime}_{n}(x)P_{m}(x)]\}^{\prime} + (m-n)(m+n+1)P_{m}(x)P_{n}(x) = 0
\label{eq:lp2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Integrating equation \eqref{eq:lp2} from -1 to 1, the first term goes to 0 and we are left with
\begin{equation}
(m-n)(m+n+1) \int\limits_{-1}^{1} P_{m}(x)P_{n}(x) dx = 0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-1}^{1} P_{m}(x)P_{n}(x) dx = 0, \quad m \ne n
\end{equation}

Comment: In eqn (2) how did you get the $(1-x^2)$ factor out of the derivative?

Answer (score -1):

By parity, for any *even* integrable function $f$, we have
$$
\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_{0}^af(x)dx
$$ giving here
$$
\int^1_{-1}(x^2-1)^ndx=2\int^1_{0}(x^2-1)^ndx.
$$