# Bessel's Inequality Proof

Tags: polynomials, summation, bessel-functions

I have a question about a step in my book, "Mathematical Methods" by McQuarrie about Bessels proof.

The solution on Bessel's inequality start with:
$$
\int^1_{-1} \left[ f (x) - \sum^N_{n=0} a_n P_n(x) \right] ^2 dx \geq 0.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1} {f^2 (x)}dx &- 2\sum^N_{n=0} a_n \int^1_{-1} f(x)P_n(x)dx\\
&+ \sum^N_{n=0}\sum^N_{m=0}a_n a_m \int^1_{-1}P_n(x)P_m(x) dx \geq 0.
\end{align}
or
$$
\int^1_{-1}f^2(x)dx \geq \sum^N_{n=0}\frac{2}{2n+1}
a^2_n.$$

Where $P_n(x)$ are the Legendre polynomials and,
$$
a_n=\frac{2n+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(x)P_n(x).
$$
I am confused why 
$$
2\sum^N_{n=0} a_n \int^1_{-1} f(x)P_n(x)dx - \sum^N_{n=0}\sum^N_{m=0}a_n a_m \int^1_{-1}P_n(x)P_m(x) dx = \sum^N_{n=0}\frac{2}{2n+1}.
$$

Comment: I assume the $P_n(x)$ are the Legendre polynomials. So what are the coefficients $a_n$?

Comment: $a_n=\frac{2n+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(x)P_n(x).$ You are correct to assume $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$a_n = \frac{2n + 1}{2} \int^1_{-1} f(x) P_n (x) \, dx \quad \Rightarrow \quad \int^1_{-1} f(x) P_n (x) \, dx = \frac{2 a_n}{2n + 1}.$$

Also, from the well-known orthogonality property for the Legendre
polynomials, namely
\begin{align*}
\int^1_{-1} P_m (x) P_n (x) \, dx = \begin{cases}
0, & m \neq n\\[1ex]
\displaystyle{\frac{2}{2n + 1}}, & m = n
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
(a proof of this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499216/legendre-polynomial-orthogonality-integral/2506847#2506847)) all terms appearing in the $m$ sum will be equal to zero except for the $m = n$ term which, from the orthogonality condition, will be equal to 
$$\int^1_{-1} P_m (x) P_n (x) \, dx = \frac{2}{2n + 1}.$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
2\sum^N_{n=0} a_n \int^1_{-1} f(x)P_n(x)dx - \sum^N_{n=0}\sum^N_{m=0}a_n a_m \int^1_{-1}P_n(x)P_m(x) dx &= 2 \sum^N_{n = 0} \frac{2 a^2_n}{2n + 1} - \sum^N_{n = 0} \frac{2 a^2_n}{2n + 1}\\
&= \sum^N_{n=0}\frac{2 a^2_n}{2n+1},
\end{align*}
as required.