# Proving orthogonality of Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

I know that such question has already been answered but what I am trying to figure out is that whether theres a more elementary way of doing so. I know the proof where we take the help of Legendre differential equation ie $$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n+1)y=0.$$ 
But I do not find it intuitive as that's not the proof that will strike you when you have just started dealing with these polynomials.

*My Attempt*

So my first approach towards this problem of proving $$\int _{-1}^{1} P_m (x) P_n (x) dx=0$$ where $P_i(x)$ is the $i$th degree Legendre polynomial is as follows:

Starting with 
$$P_m (x) = a \frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x^2-1)^m=a (x-1)^m(x+1)^m,$$ 
doing similar thing for $n$ and then somehow using Leibniz rule and saying that at $x=-1,1$ since $(x+1),(x-1)$ are $0$ respectively that's why the whole integral sums up to zero.

Comment: Rodrigues formula implies orthogonality by integration by parts, it is pretty straightforward. The non-trivial part is to deduce Rodrigues formula from the differential equation!

Comment: So with some effort  I can make this proof work right?

Comment: And I have just started this course so our professor has omitted the derivation of Rodrigue's formula

Comment: Your approach works, sure. In order to prove Rodrigues formula, you may just plug the polynomial defined by $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}$ into the differential equation and check it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So preceding with your idea of using Rodrigue's formula for the Legendre polynomials $P_n (x)$, namely
$$P_n (x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} [(x^2 - 1)^n],$$
I will start by considering the integral
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) P_n (x) \, dx.$$

Substituting Rodrigues formula for $P_n (x)$ into the above integral followed by integrating by parts $n$ times, recoginising the term $(x^2 - 1)$ repeatedly cancels at either of the end-points, one will be left with
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) P_n (x) \, dx = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!} \int_{-1}^1 f^{(n)}(x) (x^2 - 1)^n \, dx.\tag1$$

If $f(x) = P_m (x)$ where $m$ is an integer such that $0 \leqslant m < n$, since $P_m (x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ which is less than $n$, we have
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} [P_m(x)] = 0,$$
and from (1) we see that
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_m (x) P_n (x) \, dx = 0, \quad m \neq n,$$
as required.

Comment: Do we know what happens when $m=n$? Using your neat method.

Comment: @Никита Васильев If $m = n$ we cannot find $f^{(m)}(x)$ as it is no longer equal to zero. In this case you can always check out my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499216/legendre-polynomial-orthogonality-integral/2506847#2506847).