# Properties of the Legendre polynomials polynomials $P_k(x)=\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^2-1)^k$

Tags: integration, derivatives, polynomials, inner-products

For $k\in \mathbb{N}$ let $$P_k(x)=\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^2-1)^k$$
(1) Show that the $P_k$ are $L^2(-1,1)$ orthogonal.

I can't solve the integral with the definition given. I also tried to find the $k$-th polynomial using the binomial theorem, another dead end.

(2) Show that $P_k(1)=1$

(3) Show the three-term-recursion 
$$kP_k(x)=(2k-1)xP_{k-1}(x)-(k-1)P_{k-2}(x)$$

Again I don't know how this can be done without a more explicit representation of $P_k$. Is there even a more explicit representation of the polynomials? Or is some other trickery involved?

Edit: The final goal is to show these are the Legendre-polynomials.

Comment: This is the [Legendre Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html), you may want to search the web using this term alongisde your questions.

Comment: @Nyssa Will try, the ultimate goal of the exercise is to show that these are Legendre polynomials. Ergo, I can't actually use any properties of the Legendre polynomials or alternative derivations for them.

Comment: Use integration by parts. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003754/proving-that-legendre-polynomial-is-orthogonal) and the linked website.

Comment: To anyone else looking at this equation: Search for **Rodrigues Formula** in connection with the problems.