# How to simplify a partial sum obtained by Legendre polynomials

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, binomial-coefficients, legendre-polynomials

**Context**

I am working on an electrostatics problem. I have undertaken Fourier analysis. By $k$, I denote a natural number $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. I have obtained the following partial sum in terms of the even number $2k$.

$$S{(2k)}=\frac1{2^{2k}}\sum_{m=0}^{k}(-1)^m\binom{2k}{m}\binom{4k-2m}{2k}\,\frac{1}{2k-2m+1}.$$

The boundary problem that this question originates from has odd symmetry. Therefore, I expect all even Fourier coefficients--except potentially $2k=0$--to be null. This expectation is verified by the correct answer below.

**Question**

Can the above expression be simplified further?

Comment: Can you give the lead-up to this $S(k)$? That may provide for a more direct explanation of why $S(k)$ vanishes for $k>0$.

Comment: My conclusion (well, suspicion) to "shout it loud". If the original problem is to show that $\int_0^1 P_{2k}(x)\,dx=0$ for $k>0$ (armed with a suitable definition of $P_{2k}$), and your attempt is to put the explicit expression for $P_{2k}(x)$ in powers of $x$ here, then **this is a detour**. Any known idea of proving orthogonality of $P_*$, like using Rodrigues' formlua, is a great deal *faster*. (But, if we're assumed to know nothing about $P_{2k}$ but the mentioned expression, the answer by @GCab is perhaps the way to go.)

Comment: For a proof of orthogonality via the Legendre ODE, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003754/proving-that-legendre-polynomial-is-orthogonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(k) = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m}
 \left( \matrix{  2k \cr   m \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  4k - 2m \cr   2k \cr}  \right)
{1 \over {2k - 2m + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m}
 \left( \matrix{  2k \cr   m \cr}  \right){{\left( {4k - 2m} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2k\,} } }
 \over {\left( {2k} \right)!}}{1 \over {\left( {2k - 2m + 1} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} \left( {2k} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m}
 \left( \matrix{  2k \cr   m \cr}  \right)
\left( {2\left( {2k - m} \right)} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2k - 1\,} } }  \cr} 
$$

Now the [Falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
p(m,k) = \left( {2\left( {2k - m} \right)} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2k - 1\,} } 
$$
is a polynomial in $m$ with the following characteristics.
$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {k = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad } & \matrix{
  p(m,0) = \left( { - 2m} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - 1\,} }
  = {1 \over {\left( { - 2m + 1} \right)^{\underline {\,1\,} } }}
 = {1 \over { - 2m + 1}}\quad  \Rightarrow  \hfill \cr 
   \Rightarrow \quad p(0,0) = 1 \hfill \cr}   \cr 
   {1 \le k\quad  \Rightarrow \quad } & \matrix{
  p(m,k) = \left( {2\left( {2k - m} \right)} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2k - 1\,} }  \hfill \cr 
  {\rm polynomial}\,{\rm in}\,{\rm m}\,{\rm ofdegree}\;2k - 1 \hfill \cr 
  {\rm with}\,{\rm zeros} \in \left[ {k + 1,\;2k} \right] \hfill \cr}   \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

Therefore we have
$$
S(0) = 1
$$
and for $1 \le k$
$$
S(k)\quad \left| {\;1 \le k} \right. = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} \left( {2k} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^k
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  2k \cr  m \cr}  \right)p(m,k)} 
$$
Since $p(m,k) = 0$ for $k+1 \le m \le 2m$ we can extend the sum to $2k$ and multiply the summand by $1 = (-1)^{2k}$
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(k)\quad \left| {\;1 \le k} \right.\quad
  = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} \left( {2k} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{2k}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m} \left( \matrix{  2k \cr   m \cr}  \right)p(m,k)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2^{\,2k} \left( {2k} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{2k}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{2k - \,m} \left( \matrix{  2k \cr   m \cr}  \right)p(m,k)}  \cr} 
$$
Here we recognize that the sum represents the [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) (unitary step)
of order $2k$ of $p(m,k)$, and it is known (re. to the [Newton series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton%27s_series))
that the difference of a polynomial , of order greater than the degree of the same is **identically null**.

In conclusion $$S(k)= \delta _{\,k, \, 0} =\binom {0}{k}$$

Comment: @MichaelLevy: added explanation for each step

Comment: @metamorphy: oohps .. bad sign mistake, sorry and thanks for signalling: I ask MLevy to cancel the acceptance so that I may delete the answer while rethinking the conclusion , which any way is right.

Comment: @metamorphy:  I amended my answer by recasting it as the difference of order $2k$ of a polynomial of degree $2k-1$.

Comment: @MichaelLevy: cannot grasp what you mean to do: I don't see any change in the sum ..

Comment: @MichaelLevy: so meaning that $k$ could also be a multiple of $1/2$ ? and the sum going from $0$ to $floor (k/2)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $k>0$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S(2k)}&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{2k}{m}\binom{4k-2m}{2k}\frac{1}{2k-2m+1}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k2^{k+1}}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\binom{2k}{m}\binom{4k-2m}{2k-2m+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k2^{k+1}}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\binom{2k}{m}[z^{2k-2m+1}](1+z)^{4k-2m}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k2^{k+1}}[z^{2k+1}](1+z)^{4k}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m\binom{2k}{m}\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{2m}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k2^{k+1}}[z^{2k+1}](1+z)^{4k}\left(1-\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^2\right)^{2k}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k2^{k+1}}[z^{2k+1}](1+2z)^{2k}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{4k-2m}{2k}\frac{1}{2k-2m+1}=\binom{4k-2m}{2k-2m}\frac{1}{2k-2m+1}
  =\binom{4k-2m}{2k-2m-1}\frac{1}{2k}$.
- In (3) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1). We also set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ which doesn't change the sum since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we do some simplifications.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since (a [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues%27_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas) formula which easily follows from e.g. Rodrigues') $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^m\binom{n}{m}\binom{2n-2m}{n}x^{n-2m},$$ the given expression is equal to $\int_0^1 P_{2k}(x)\,dx=\frac12\int_{-1}^1 P_{2k}(x)\,dx$.

This is $1$ for $k=0$ and $0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: @MichaelLevy: Then it depends on how do you *define* the Legendre polynomials. With Rodrigues' formula $P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ used *as a definition*, $\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx=0$ for $n\neq m$ (and particularly the case $m=0$) is *very easy to prove* using integration by parts, as well as the "known formula" above (expand $(x^2-1)^n$ and differentiate termwise). **So I'm not sure whether it is a "backwards" way.** (Unless you prefer a "Legendre-free" approach.)

Comment: To justify the integral over the Legendre polynomials, note that $\int_{-1}^1 P_m (x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^1 P(m)P_0(x)\,dx$ since $P_0(x)=1$. So this is just a direct consequence of the orthogonality of Legendre polynomials. (And if you want to prove said orthogonality, there's better ways to do that than considering particular sums.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: this is addressed to OP rather than me, right? ;)

Comment: It's addressed to anyone who hasn't seen the $P_0(x)=1$ trick :). (Though I see now I typoed $P_m(x)$ as $P(m)$, silly me.)